# Differentiability of $z \, Log(1+\overline z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I had complex analysis exam today and one problem was to find all points where function $$f(z)=z \, Log(1+\overline z)$$ is holomorphic. Here $Log$ means principal value of complex logarithm.

I have done many same type of problems but couldn't find an easy way to solve this one. I tried to use CR-equations but since the complex conjugate is inside the Logarithm it was hard for me to separate the real and imaginary part of the function (which should be possible with polar coordinates?).

My guess is that this function is only differentiable at 0 and there is no points where it's holomorphic.

I would like to see as many ways as possible to solve this problem.

Comment: Doesn't it depend where the branch cut for the log is?

Comment: Yeah well that's all what was in the question. But like I wrote here $Log$ means the principal value meaning that $Arg(z) \in (- \pi, \pi]$. I'm not really good with the branches because I'm not too familiar with complex logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

For  $z=0$, using directly the limit definition you see the derivative is $0$.

And for non-zero  values, we just need to investigate $ \log (1+\bar{z})=f(z)$ , and it is differentiable nowhere. Note that $e^{f(z)}=1+\bar{z}$  is  not differentiable.

So, it is differentiable only at the origin and nowhere analytic.

Comment: My lecturer actually said this approach is wrong, or at least need more clarification. He said you really have to use CR-equations.